# Create plugin gulp with stream

Tags: javascript, json, plugins, gulp

I created plugin for send json data in json file.

But I don't understand why send my object json in pipe, and not write file directly in my plugin.

I want use my plugin whit this syntax:

```
gulp.task('js-hash', function()
{
    // Get all js in redis
    gulp.src('./build/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(getHashFile('/build/js/'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/hash.json'));
});
```

And not that:

```
gulp.task('js-hash', function()
{
    // Get all js in redis
    gulp.src('./build/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(getHashFile('./build/js/hash.json', '/build/js/'));
});
```

This is my plugin:

```
var through = require('through2');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
var PluginError = gutil.PluginError;

// Consts
const PLUGIN_NAME = 'get-hash-file';
var json = {};

function getHashFile(filename, basename)
{
    if (!filename) {
        throw PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, "Missing filename !");
    }

    // Creating a stream through which each file will pass
    var stream = through.obj(function (file, enc, callback) {
        if (file.isNull()) {
            this.push(file); // Do nothing if no contents
          return callback();
        }

        if (file.isBuffer()) {
            var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(file.contents)).digest('hex');
            json[file.path.replace(file.cwd+basename, '')] = hash;

            return callback();
        }

        if (file.isStream()) {
            this.emit('error', new PluginError(PLUGIN_NAME, 'Stream not supported!'));
            return callback();
        }
    }).on('finish', function () {
        fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(json), function(err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
        });
    });


    // returning the file stream
    return stream;
}


// Exporting the plugin main function
module.exports = getHashFile;
```

Your are idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from doing this... besides [not respecting plugins guidelines](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md)!

Users actually assume a plugin will stream files and that they can pipe them to other plugins.

If I get your code right, you're trying to generate a file that contains all sha hashes of inbound files. Why not let users take this file and pipe it to other plugins? You'd be surprised what people could do.

While this question looks a bit opinion-based, you could definitely put the focus on how to deal with files that may not belong to the main stream of files. Issues like this can be found in many plugins; for example, [gulp-uglify authors are wondering how they can add source-maps without mixing js and source map downstream](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/16).